# Error while defining a vhost in rabbitmq using helm stable/rabbitmq-ha

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to create vhosts in a rabbitmq helm deployment by setting the variables "definitions", as instructed in the documentation [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha/values.yaml) but I just get the following error:

```
[error] <0.329.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.329.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {error,not_json} in application_master:init/4 line 138
[info] <0.43.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {error,not_json}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{error,not_json}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{bad_return,{{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{error,not_json}}}}})
```

Do you know which one is the correct format? This is the definition I'm using:

```
rabbitmq-ha:
  definitions:
    vhosts: |-
      {
        name: "/name"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was json format mistake. After the **vhosts: |-** must be of json format. So **name** should be also between quotes. This would be the final result:

```
rabbitmq-ha:
  definitions:
    vhosts: |-
      {
        "name": "/name"
      }
```